# Phpmyadmin date/time calculate

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a wordpress blog, and it has like 3000+ posts, some posts in database shows **post_date_gmt** is `1970-01-01 0:0:0`, so to fix it I manually UPDATE the post_date_gmt to equal the post_date by using this below:

```
UPDATE wp_post SET 'post_date_gmt' = 'post_date';
```

but here comes the problem: I need the GMT date to reduced by `8 hours`.

Is there any ways to batch increase or decrease the date filed in `PHPmyadmin` like UPDATE something? 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
UPDATE wp_post SET 'post_date_gmt' = DATE_SUB('post_date',INTERVAL 8 HOUR);
```

You can increase with: `DATE_ADD`

And use `MICROSECOND, SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, YEAR` with `INTERVAL`

Comment: Thank you Mischievous, that perfectly solved my problem here, Thank you!